# boostrap col-auto taking up inordinate space

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm having trouble understanding why `col-auto` is taking more space than the minimum required for its contents.

See this example http://jsfiddle.net/ugt0x5nf/6/. Note, rendered window must be widened to > 768px to see the issue.

See how the last column w/ `col-md-auto` takes up more space than is necessary to fit the `<button>` within it. See this screenshot. [image: col-auto too wide]

Why? What I want to happen is the last column is exactly the width of the button and the rest of the other columns expand to compensate.

My code is like:

```
<form>
  <div class="form-row d-flex">
    <div class="col-md-1">
      <input class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <input class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <input class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <input class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-auto">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-link">X</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider:

```
<form>
  <div class="form-row d-flex">
    <div class="col-md-1">
      <input class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <input class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="col w-100">
      <input class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="col w-100">
      <input class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="flex-shrink-1">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-link">X</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

With this, the two cols that were col-md-4 will stretch and the button col will shrink to the width of the button.

Comment: Thanks! This works nicely. My only question is, why does this work and my original didn't?

Comment: I believe it's because you had two divs of `col-md-4` combined with the `col-md-1` and `col-md-2` which is 11 columns; 11 out of 12 in Bootstrap. The col-md-auto was taking up the remaining space - one column - but only the width of the button yet leaving extra, unoccupied, space at the end of the flexed row.  Changing the 'col-md-4' classes to `col w-100` allowed those columns to flex wider and the `flex-shrink-1` gave them extra space to do such and removed the unoccupied space at the end of the row.

Comment: Indeed. Just looking at the docs, I wouldn't expect this: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#variable-width-content. It says `-auto` is used to `size columns based on the natural width of their content.`.